# difference between store data in drawable folder and store in sdcard

Tags: android

**hi**

can you elaborate that what is the difference between store multiple images in `Drawable folder` and store in `sdcard` ?
which is best for **memory management** point of view ?

**thanks

nik**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory point of SDCARD is best but it may make application slower.And al;so you have to provide permission and path for SDCARD which is not require for Drawable folder.If less number of images having small in size can be put in drawable folder else you may go for SDCARD.

Comment: i have 100 images and currently load in 300 mb mobile device so what will you prefer

Comment: i think if we put 100 images in drawable then initially load it in RAM.but if we put in sdcard so one by one come and remove if we want right?

Comment: and one more thing is that it is not matter of 100 mb only i want more than it

Comment: I think if one by one will come then it will take more time as i specified in my answer.

Comment: but currently problem of memory, crash my app